# Create service bus topic request gives exception Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus, servicebus

When I try to create a service bus topic programmatically using the sample app (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management), Azure gives **Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'** exception.

I have verified my TenantId, ClientId, ClientSecret, SubscriptionId and namespace name several times and they seem correct to me. My service bus pricing tier is "Standard".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error, seems you did not add your service principal as a role to your service bus.

You could follow the steps:

Navigate to the azure portal -> your service bus or the subscription whcih your service bus located -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search your service principal with name and add it as a role(e.g. `Owner`) -> `Save`.

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-the-application-to-a-role).

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue. I had to search with the whole name of the app to grant the owner access because I was a guest user.